# Facebook is not showing Shared links image properly. "og:image"

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

Thumbnails for posts of my site https://business-students.net/ is not appearing in Facebook.
When I share a link on Facebook, It shows the correct preview of the link thumbnail, but when posted, Thumbnail disappears. (see below)

Post Link for example: https://business-students.net/f3-fa-mcqs-quiz-1-acca/

[Screenshot before posting/sharing a link. (preview)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb5Gb.jpg)

[Screenshot after posting/sharing a link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Qt7.jpg)

Even Facebook debugger shows a correct image of the post. [See this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsxFZ.jpg)

But it disappears when it is shared on facebook. [see [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Qt7.jpg)]

Even, the homepage of the site doesn't show any thumbnail image there.
[(See here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOXUY.jpg)

I tried to scrape so many times but no use.

I thought My website might be missing Meta Tag for Social Media, So I added these

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $seo_description; ?>" />
<meta property="og:keywords" content="<?php echo $seo_keywords; ?>" />

<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" />
<link rel="image_src" href="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" />

<meta name="description" content="YOUR_DESCRIPTION_HERE" />

<meta name="keywords" content="YOUR_KEYWORDS_HERE, SEPERATED_BY_COMA" />

<meta content='English' name='language'/>
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us"/>
<html lang="en-us"/>
<title lang="en-us"/>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
<b:else/>
<title><data:blog.pageName/> - <data:blog.title/></title>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription != ""'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='description'/>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "archive"'>
<meta content='noindex, nofollow' name='robots'/>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' name='keywords'/>
<meta content='index, follow' name='robots'/>
</b:if>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageTitle != data:blog.title'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' name='keywords'/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/></b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
<meta content='global' name='distribution'/>
<meta content='1 days' name='revisit'/>
<meta content='1 days' name='revisit-after'/>
<meta content='document' name='resource-type'/>
<meta content='all' name='audience'/>
<meta content='general' name='rating'/>
<meta content='all' name='robots'/>
<meta content='en-us' name='language'/>
<meta content='USA' name='country'/>
<meta content='@twitter.com/example.Com' name='twitter:site'/>
<meta content='@example.Com' name='twitter:creator'/>
<meta content='example.Com' name='author'/>
<meta content='contact@example.Com' name='email'/>
</b:if>
```

But still the issue is not resolved.

Please help to resolve this strange issue.

Comment: I don't see `og:image` anywhere under the example URL you have given. `twitter:image` appears to be there, but `og:image` doesn't.

Comment: @CBroe, then let me know, how can I add ```og:image```.

Comment: How could we possibly know, why what you tried did not work? _You_ will need to go and investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

I think because the image has been changed since, You would need to run it through the Facebook sharing debugger.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fbusiness-students.net%2Ff3-fa-mcqs-quiz-1-acca%2F

Once I clicked 'Scrape Again' it updated to the newest image.

Comment: It appears correctly in debuging but disappeared when shared on facebook.

Comment: It seems to be showing [link]https://business-students.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/F3-FA-Financial-Accounting-Quiz-1.webp[/link] as an image for me?  Maybe try a .jpg image instead of .webp format and see if that is the issue.